# Why the word "Pronounced" used before word DEAD?

Tags: sentence-construction

For Example:

> Yesterday, Tina Michaels **Pronounced** dead at 7:30 PM at Hospital.

In above sentence, **Pronounced** is used before **dead**. Why so ?

Comment: Did you look "pronounced" up in the dictionary? What do you think it means in that sentence?

Comment: for the records, if someone is in official hands at the time of their death, the death is 'pronounced' along with the time

Comment: ***Pronounced** [adjective]* means ***declared to be** [adjective]* (usually, by some kind of authority professionally and/or legally qualified to make such a judgement). So you example should read *Yesterday, Tina Michaels **was** pronounced dead*.

Comment: This looks like headlinese to me, which would explain the missing "was". What is the source of this?

Comment: To add to FumbleFingers's comment, "death" isn't as clear-cut as it may seem.  There are degrees of medical death, reflecting the ability of modern medicine to revive after a death-like state, there's death in a religious sense, death in a legal sense, etc.  They aren't always the same thing.  People have been mistaken for dead or been considered dead and that turned out not to be the case or they were able to be revived.  For legal purposes, someone in an official capacity declares that the person is considered dead.  That's the pronouncement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another meaning of "pronounce" is *to announce* or *to declare*. Etymologically, this word origated from Latin ***"pro- = out, forth"*** + **"nuntiare=announce"**.